# How to get exact starting position of a first cell (x, y) in UITableview?

Tags: iphone, ios

How to get exact starting position of a first cell in UITableview?

Comment: It is not the same point of the table view?

Comment: There could be a header view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to get the rect in your table

```
CGRect cellRectInTable = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then you get convert that to super view

```
CGRect cellInSuperview = [tableView convertRect:cellRectInTable toView:[tableView superview]];
```

You may also have luck with

```
CGRect cellInWindow = [tableView convertRect:cellRectInTable toView:nil];
```

Then you can access the origins of those rects

```
...rect.origin.x
...rect.origin.y
```

[Apple Docs UIView convRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCEAJCI)

[Apple Docs rectForRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/rectForRowAtIndexPath:)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using:

```
int y = cell.frame.origin.y;
int x = cell.frame.origin.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the following after you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: in the delegate method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: then store it in a CGPoint property.

To compact it more

```
if (self.indexPath.row == 0 && self.indexPath.section == 0){
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y);
    self.firstPoint = point;
}
```

Of course, you could just put self.firstPoint where point is, but I left them separate to demonstrate.

You can also get the cell from the index path in any given method by calling

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int numberOfCells = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; // whatever section number
if (numberOfCells > 0) {
    NSIndexPath *firstCellIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *firstCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:firstCellIndexPath];
    NSLog(@"%d, %d", firstCell.frame.origin.x, firstCell.frame.origin.y);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to get the cell. Just ask the table view for the rect of the indexPath.